# Populate username and password into website login page when accessed from mobile App

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, joomla, authentication

I have Joomla website and mobile App that's running on different server (programmed using JavaScript). Both belong to the same party, and the users have similar accounts on both with identical ID's and passwords (although these ID's and passwords are stored in different DB's, we make sure they are synchronized and identical).

Users log in to the App (session is created on the App server) and navigate to the button (website). Upon tapping on the button, it opens new window displaying (login page of the website) shown below. They have to insert their credentials once again and then access to their accounts.

[image]

I wonder if there is a way to automatically populate the username and the password into username and password fields, such that users only have to click on (login) button. It is annoying that they have to insert their credentials twice. So this would help a lot as a plan B.

If that is possible, what is the logic should I follow? (e.g. I know how to submit php form using JavaScript to this website, but is that the way to go? )

Answer (score 0):

Your best option is `SharedPreferences`, but you will need to construct some sort of cryptographic store. Make sure you're encrypting the password before writing it to disk.

If possible consider modify the server to use a token to provide the access, something like [OAuth](http://code.google.com/p/oauth/).

After that, you just have to read the stored values and assign it to the `text fields`

Comment: Apart from the security concerns (this is of very low security App), is not their more straightforward way to assign the values to the text fields directly from the mobile App. The username and password are stored in the App localStorage in plain text

Comment: what kind objects are the text boxes? or the app is a `webView` and you connect to url? By other side... even you app is low security, storing user/pass in plain text is **TOTALLY DISCOURAGED!**

Comment: If you mean I can run the App in the browser with url, yes, I can. I'm not sure what do you mean by objects kind, but when inspect text fields, this is what I get: <div class="login-fields"><label id="password-lbl" for="password" class="">Password</label>   <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="manager1" class="inputbox validate-password" size="25" placeholder="Password">   </div>

Comment: if so it's up to user and browser settings to remember user and password or not...

Comment: They can do that, but my intention is populate the username and password for them and then it is up to them to erase them (which they won't as all complain about re-inserting username and passwords)

Comment: so if you have the data stored in plain text, simply pass it to javascript and put it in the fields with `document.getElementById("password").value = valueOfPassword`...

Comment: This line should be on button click?currently I have something like this: `window.open('https://......', '_blank', 'location=yes'); ` on website button click